# How do I capture the value in a select list loop in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, foreach, key

I have a gender array as an example, but I am also using longer select list such as states. I want to capture the option value in a PHP varible that the client side user chooses. Then I can use that captured value in an email message.

```
function genderList() {
$gender = array('M'=>"Male",'F'=>"Female",);
return $gender;
}
$gender = genderList();

$email_form = '<?php $states = statesList(); ?>
<form class="aw-contact-form" method="post" action="' . get_permalink() . '">
                <label for="cf_gender">' . $label_gender . '</label>
                <select name="gender" id="cf_gender">
                    <option selected="selected"></option>';
                        foreach ($gender as $key => $value) {
                        $email_form .= '<option value="' . $key . '">' . $value .      '</option>';
                        }
                $email_form .= '</select>
</form>

return $email_form;
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: when the form is submitted, the gender will be stored in $_POST["gender"] on the receiving page. Whatever you name the form field (for example name="gender" or name="state") will be the name of the key in $_POST ($_POST["gender"] or $_POST["state"]).

Comment: Just tested it and works! Awesome. Thanks again for the quick answer.